# Run rake task on aws instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2

I have a problem when I run a take task inside an AWS instance.
That instance has a autoscaling/loadbalancer configuration that creates a new instance as it reaches certain pre-defined limits.

The rails project has a rake task that makes a lot of database insert/updates every night.

But when that rake task is executing, the autoscaling feature creates a new instance and the process that was running the task is lost.

Is there any solution that I can make in order to solve this problem?

The problem is: not lost the task running process every time aws launch a new instance from autoscaling configuration.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A few option you could try, depending on your application design:

1. run the task on a separate instance that is not part of the autoscaling group and that you spin up as needed (perhaps in a docker?).
2. re-engineer the tasks to be distributed so that new instances don't matter.
3. schedule pre-scale of the group so that the required instances are added before you start your rake tasks.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/schedule_time.html#recurrence-schedule-cron